# Redux-Thunk: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: android, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

Can't solve this problem, using react-native and redux-thunk.

I am trying to post data to firebase.io and repeatedly get the same error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

reducers/index.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import PlacesReducer from './placesReducer'


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  places : PlacesReducer,
    });

let composeEnhancers = compose;

if (__DEV__) {
    composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
}

const configureStore = () => {
    return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
};

export default configureStore;
```

actions/index.js

```
export const addPlace = (placeName, location, image) => {
    return dispatch => {
        const placeData = {
            name: placeName,
            location: location
        };
        fetch("https://awesome-places-b592c.firebaseio.com/placesReducer.json", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(placeData)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(parsedRes => {
            console.log(parsedRes);
        });
    };
};
```

reducers/placesReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  places: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_PLACE":
      return {
        ...state,
        places: state.places.concat({
          key: Math.random(),
          name: action.placeName,
          image: {
            uri: action.image.uri,
            location: action.location
          }
        })
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

All help is appreciated, thank you.

---

**UPDATE**

Added initialState argument to the `createStore()` function in reducers/index.js

```
const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, {places: []}, applyMiddleware(thunk));
};
```

Still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to `dispatch` the actions after the async request is completed

```
.then(parsedRes => {
     console.log(parsedRes);
     dispatch({
       type: YOUR_REDUCER_TYPE,
       parsedRes
    })
});
```

Also as mentioned in the `createStore` [docs](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/createstore), you need to add the `initialState`

```
(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer)
```

Comment: Still wont work. I wasn't dispatching as I just wanted to see want response I was getting.

Comment: Added the reducer code, about to try adding the initialState to the `createStore`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the code as follows:

```
export const addPlace = (placeName, location, image) => {
    //return dispatch => {
        const placeData = {
            name: placeName,
            location: location
        };
        fetch("https://awesome-places-b592c.firebaseio.com/placesReducer.json", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(placeData)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(parsedRes => {
            console.log(parsedRes);
            // you may tweak this
            // use ...parsedRes following the reducer code you paste,
            // I assume location, placeName and image are inside parsedRes
            dispatch({ type:"ADD_PLACE", ...parsedRes })
        });
    //};
};
```

Then in the reducer:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_PLACE":
      // check the action content
      console.log(action)
      return {
        ...state,
        places: state.places.concat({
          key: Math.random(),
          name: action.placeName,
          image: {
            uri: action.image.uri,
            location: action.location
          }
        })
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Made no difference putting the `dispatch()` in the `.then()`. Maybe because I have my redux-thunk setup wrong but I don't see how.